# How to unzip nested zip files in Gradle

Tags: gradle, zip

I am struggling to extract contents of nested zip file. What I have is something like that:

- `artifacts`

  - `big.zip`

    - `inner1.zip`
    - `inner2.zip`
  - `1.zip`
  - `2.zip`

Now I'm trying to unzip all from `artifacts`. I've tried to unzip the `big.zip` first in a `temp` folder. After that unzip `1.zip` and `2.zip` and finally the `inner.zip` from the `temp` folder. Further I'm trying to aggregate the tasks with `dependsOn` and `mustRunAfter` and facing a problem here. If I execute the tasks one by one, it is working fine, but when I aggregate the tasks the unzip `inner.zip` is not done and I'm getting `NO-SOURCE`.

```
task unpackL1 (type:Copy) { 
    from zipTree(file(new File("artifacts/big.ZIP")))
    into tempPath   
    doLast {
        println 'Level 1 extracted'
    }   
}
task unpackL2 (type:Copy) {     
    def treeFileL1 = fileTree(artifacts) {
        include "**/*.zip"
        exclude "big.ZIP"
    }
    treeFileL1.each {       
        from zipTree(it)
        into destPath
    }   
    doLast {
        println 'Level 2 extracted'
    }   
}
task unpackFinal (type:Copy) {      
    def treeFileL2 = fileTree(tempPath)  { // tempPath is the destination of unpackL1
        include "**/*.zip"
    }
    treeFileL2.each {       
        from zipTree(it)
        into destPath
    }
    doLast {        
        println 'All extracted'
    }   
}
unpackL2.mustRunAfter unpackL1
unpackL2.dependsOn(unpackL1)
unpackFinal.mustRunAfter unpackL2
unpackFinal.dependsOn(unpackL2)
```

My questions are:

- Why I'm getting `NO-SOURCE` if I aggregate the tasks, but not if I run the tasks one by one?
- Further is there a better solution to unzip the nested zip files? Without temporary folder?